# How should I disclose self-promotion in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

In questions, if you refer to a product or service created by yourself, you need to declare your involvement: for example, "*I* created a library" rather than "There is a library".

How should we handle this in documentation? I've created a library to better handle Fragments in Android Anko code, and wish to mention it in the Anko topic of the Kotlin wiki. Since an example generally has many contributors, using "I" might get confusing for readers. Do we still need to declare our involvement in the product or service in documentation, and if so, how?

Comment: Underlying question: is it advisable to use the personal pronoun "I" in *documentation* at any place? I don't think I've ever seen it used as such^ in Mozilla's JavaScript reference, or on MSDN. (^ `int i;` is okay, although it violates the "use descriptive variable names" rule.)

Comment: It's definitely not appropriate to use "I" in documentation. There'll have to be another way.

Comment: I agree with Pekka - The only other way I could think to do it is "OrangeFlash81 created a library", but that sounds odd.

Comment: First of all, consider if documentation _really_ requires a link to some external library, in the first place. Usually, the answer is _"nope"_. Unless that library has a topic of it's own, that is.

Comment: @Cerbrus We have this topic request: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/topic-requests/2058 … It turns out in PHP we have no native event loops, so you typically need to build one yourself or use an existing one. You really don't want to write your own, it's so easy to get it wrong... Now, there are about 3 general purpose event loop libraries for PHP currently… Should they be mentioned or not? [I.e. shall we mention the sane way to do it?]

Comment: I second Cerbrus. Documentations should in general NOT show how to do this or that a little more neat than it was supposed to be, but the normal way. Regarding the PHP stuff: In this case I would suggest to create an extra topic on event loops, and mention the most widely used libraries there, along with the info on how to write one on your own.

Comment: Whoever said that self promotion was actually ok in the first place?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier It's usually fine on SO as long as the poster notes it. The usual quality standards still apply, so a link-only answer of "use this library" doesn't cut it.

Comment: @chrylis Exactly, on SO. While documentation *is* a part of SO, everything on SO desn't apply over there. For instance, it's not designed to ask questions. Similarly, I feel the place of self-promotion should be discussed in it's own right.

Comment: A more important question would be: should anyone promote anything other than the actual solution... no solution implies a problem... umm... difficult, should anyone promote anything that isn't inherent to the tag (like that?)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notwithstanding the issue of whether you *should* self-promote, there is currently no system in place for adding disclosures or really any other kind of meta-discussion about Documentation content, so the best thing you can do is probably to add in your answer <kbd>**Note:** Original author created this library.</kbd>

Then:

- No-one can accuse you of non-disclosure,
- The content can be removed if it's considered to be inappropriate self-promotion, and
- Someone else can remove the disclosure later if there are no objections to the self-promotion, and the disclosure is only serving as a distraction.

Comment: I very much agree with this idea. I've changed my mind about including my own libraries now - if a library isn't useful enough to a) have its own tag or b) already be documented, then it's probably not worthy of documentation at all, like in my case. If your library does match those cases, then the promotion isn't really "self".

Comment: I'm going to strongly recommend against using the `<kbd>` tag, as it has implications for those using screen readers. And imo, it looks horrible for anything that isn't a keyboard key.