# How to handle self-promotional changes

Tags: discussion, documentation, self-promotion

This is mostly about https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/95530

A change similar to that one was rejected shortly before, among other things due to the fact that the author promoted their own product. (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/95515) Then it resurfaced, fixing another problem but still being self-promotional.

As you can see, I voted to `Reject -> Other` and someone else even voted `Reject -> Spam`.

Apart from the fact that I do not understand why the 2:2 ties resulted in *different* decisions, I'm not sure how to handle this. If it would have been plagiarism, I would just delete the example again. But in a case that is not so clear cut, I don't want to circumvent the decision of the community nor start an edit war. However, I suspect that the two reviewers might not have noticed that the author also operates the software being advertised. Overruling two reject votes based on what might be a simple oversight doesn't feel right, either.

What should be done about this case in particular?

What are the general guidelines on self promotion in documentation?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention it originally but there is a question disussing the *other* side, i.e. [how to disclose in documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329125/how-should-i-disclose-self-promotion-in-documentation) already.

Comment: And, since it's been approved, you can't reply to the author's comment asking how to provide the suitable disclosure, is that right? If we ever get the discussion section mentioned in the last update, that might help, or you could point the OP to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329125/215552) regarding how to disclose..

Comment: Yeah, I actually typed my answer but then was unable to post it. So, how am I supposed to point them to that question without starting a discussion on something unrelated?

Comment: Wow I just noticed that his code is copyrighted as well. Meaning that it's using isn't ever viable for a huge section of the http://stackoverflow.com audience :|

Comment: I seems to be under an [MIT License](https://github.com/FarhadJabiyev/EntityGraphOperations/blob/master/LICENSE). Is this actually unsuitable for so many users?